# How to use foreach in 'if' condition, Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I am using laravel 5.8 
I want to create an invoice of the customer on login,
the scenario is that I want to check on login that if the due date of an invoice is equal to the current time so create new invoice of the same customer.
here is my code

> Login Controller

```
public function login(Request $req)
{

    $this->validate($req, [
        'email' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required'
    ]);

   if (\Auth::attempt(['email' => $req->email, 'password' => $req->password])) {
        $today = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d');
        $all = Invoice::where('due_date', $today)->get()

        foreach($all as $row) {

            $addinvoice = Invoice::create([
            'customer_id' => $row->customer_id,
            'account_title' => $row->account_title,
            'slug' => str_slug($row->account_title),
            'perpared_date' => $today,
            'amount' => $row->amount,

            ]);

            if ($row->due_date == '1 month') {
                $interval = $today->addMonths()->format('Y-m-d');
            }
            if ($row->due_date == '3 month') {
                $interval = $today->addMonths(3)->format('Y-m-d');
            }
            if ($row->due_date == '6 month') {
                $interval = $today->addMonths(6)->format('Y-m-d');
            }
            if ($row->due_date == '12 month') {
                $interval = $today->addMonths(12)->format('Y-m-d');
            }
            $addinvoice['due_date'] = $interval;

        }

        return redirect()->to('/admin/customers/list');
    } else {
        return redirect()->back()->with(['msg' => 'Invalid Email or Password']);
    }       
}
```

Here I am getting an error after login

```
syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH)
```

Can one help me in fixing it?

Comment: you are missing `;` at the end of `Invoice::where('due_date', $today)->get()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you forgot semicolon for this line

```
 $all = Invoice::where('due_date', $today)->get()
```

put semicolon for`->get()`

Comment: Thanks alot mohammad fallahpoor

Comment: dear mohammad fallahpoor, for checking that this is creating invoice or not, I changed the due date of a customer as today's but I could not find any invoice created. Can you help me plzz?